# No Sound in Elementary 5.1 on Acer Swift 5 sf514

Tags: release-hera, sound, acer

Help me please fix the problem with sound.

---

alsactl init
alsactl: init:1757: No soundcards found...

---

lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 34c8 (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 136f
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
    Memory at 601d160000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 601d000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, sof_pci_dev

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 136f
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at 601d16a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 3040 [size=32]

---

dmesg | grep "audio"

[ 4.119981] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: warning: No matching ASoC machine driver found
[ 4.119988] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
[ 4.120132] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
[ 4.124535] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[ 5.606185] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 5
[ 5.606186] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: using HDA machine driver skl_hda_dsp_generic now
[ 5.608036] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: codec #0 probe error, ret: -2
[ 5.612971] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: Direct firmware load for intel/sof/sof-icl.ri failed with error -2
[ 5.612973] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: request firmware intel/sof/sof-icl.ri failed err: -2
[ 5.612974] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: failed to load DSP firmware -2

Comment: Try updating your kernel, choose one from here https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ and go into amd64 section. Download all the lines that contain "generic" and "all". To install them open terminal in the correct folder and execute `sudo apt install ./lin*.deb`

Comment: Thanks, I 'll try. But can this be fixed without updating the entire kernel?

Because on Linux Mint 19.3 (Kernel 5.0) the sound works.

Comment: Write `dmesg | grep audio` on terminal and look for an error line. Somehow it is loading the wrong kernel module. Should have loaded snd_hda_intel.

Comment: dmesg | grep audio
[    4.119981] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: warning: No matching ASoC machine driver found
[    4.119988] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
[    4.120132] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
[    4.124535] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])

Comment: 5.606185] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 5
[    5.606186] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: using HDA machine driver skl_hda_dsp_generic now
[    5.608036] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: codec #0 probe error, ret: -2
[    5.612971] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: Direct firmware load for intel/sof/sof-icl.ri failed with error -2
[    5.612973] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: request firmware intel/sof/sof-icl.ri failed err: -2
[    5.612974] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: failed to load DSP firmware -2

Comment: What should i do ?

Comment: I don't know. Let's see if somebody else can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Install "PulseAudio Volume Control" from AppCenter.
and reboot.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn 't help.
The system does not see audio devices

________________________________________________________________________alsactl init alsactl: init:1757: No soundcards found...